# How to determine if record is a part of NOT IN versus doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, notin

Rephrasing the original post.

How can I use the following query, or similar:

```
select * from table where name="Jack" AND ID NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5) ;
```

To determine the difference between:

1. `Jack` record found, but its ID exists in (1,2,3,4,5), thus nothing returned
2. and, No `Jack` records found, thus nothing returned

Is this possible with an IF statement or something similar...or is there a better method for doing this?

Comment: `IN(false)` and `NOT IN(true)` are the same. Have a look at http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_exists_clause_vs_in_clause.htm#:~:text=The%20EXISTS%20clause%20is%20much,can%20compare%20everything%20with%20NULLs.

Comment: Any chance you could rephrase your question a little?
What do you mean by "tell me"? `IN` and `NOT IN` are filters, they allow to return more or less rows.
What's your expected output?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your question.

Comment: I clarified the question

Comment: The easiest way is with two queries. One checks if `Jack` exists at all, another gets all the rows that are NOT IN the list.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You can use case to make a pseudo-column of 1 when in the set and 0 when not, or vice versa, and sum the pseudo columns to see how many time the id is in the set and how many time is it not, for each name.  select name, sum( in_ct ) in_ct, sum( out_ct ) out_ct from ( Select name, case when id in (list) then 1 else 0 end in_ct, case when id not in (list) then 1 else 0 end out_ct from table) x group by name;

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: One query to get the status ("match", "found Jack, but wrong id", "found no Jack") and the match(es) if any outer joined:

```
select s.status, t.*
from
(
  select
    case 
      when sum(name = 'Jack' and id not in (1,2,3,4,5)) then 'MATCH'
      when sum(name = 'Jack') then 'WRONG ID'
      else 'NO JACK'
    end as status
  from t
) s
left join t on t.name = 'Jack' and t.id not in (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02733107f41bc51600a422f2911c6f6b